# Magento email template: Block template inheritance broken

Tags: magento

**Problem**

When I try to add a block into my transactional email template in the following manner:

`{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='invent/baskettimer/email_items.phtml' record=$record}}`

I get the following error, and nothing is rendered.

`CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/invent/baskettimer/email_items.phtml`

**Troubleshooting**

- Normally this warning points to a typo which is breaking the inheritance but I have quadruple checked and this should work.
- I then copied the file into the base and did a test, it rendered correctly.
- Create a custom block and set the template, same error is displayed.

**Theory**

To me it seems template inheritance is broken / not implemented for emails, so it is always looking in base, I cannot put my templates there so I am not sure how to call them.

**Possible workarounds**

- Render the block to html then send it to as a variable to render, problem with this is I am sending the emails from Model level and am having a hard time pre rendering the block, even with a helper.
- Render the data using a method, don't really want to do this as it is message / against MVC.

Any help is much appreciated.

---

**Bounty update**

So I have traced down the problem, it is probably an easy solution now.

The problem is that I am calling it from a cronjob does not have the correct store view, it is fairly easy to replicate similar situation by using a shell script, then changing the _appCode to null.

```
<?php
require_once 'abstract.php';

class Mage_Shell_Shell extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{

    protected $_appCode = ''; // works - remove to not work

    /**
     * Run script
     *
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Mage::getModel('invent_baskettimer/email')->sendJob();

    }

}

$shell = new Mage_Shell_Shell();
$shell->run();
```

So basically the question has become:

**How do I call a `block->toHtml()` regardless of store view?**

Comment: Is `invent` your theme? Try the path without theme: `baskettimer/email_items.phtml`

Comment: @SimonH No invent is a folder within the custom theme.

Comment: Did you try to set your theme explicitly with `_theme='yourTheme'`? `{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='invent/baskettimer/email_items.phtml' record=$record _theme='yourTheme'}}`

Comment: @SimonH Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately that does not work either, trying to debug the process now through the core files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not way of setting a cronjob to be like that. Lucky magento lets you emulate your store views, see the following to emulate the default store.

```
public function cronjob()
{
    $iDefaultStoreId = Mage::app()
        ->getWebsite()
        ->getDefaultGroup()
        ->getDefaultStoreId();

    $appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
    $initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($iDefaultStoreId);

    .. do your stuff  here ..   

    $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
}
```

For more info see: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/emulate-store-in-magento/